# How to properly remove mold from camera body?

Tags: maintenance

Long story short, I'm living in Vietnam which has a pretty hectic rainy season. Thankfully it's almost over. My room unfortunately got a fair amount of mold that seeped through the concrete walls. After advising my landlord to not just paint over the walls he came in and did it anyways releasing spores all over my apartment. 2 days after the painting I came home to find a ton of mold growing on the body of my camera that was sitting out in the room as well as other various items around my home. I only found mold on items that were sitting out. Not in any cabinets. I wiped the body off and after two days of not seeing any mold come back i'm hoping that I'm in the clear.
As it is still quite humid i'm leaving my camera where it gets a fair amount of sunlight while also turning the AC on to hopefully dry out the room a bit. My lens that was attached looks to have a small speck of fungus forming within the front.
I've been on a pretty steady mission of wiping down my entire apartment with a vinegar and water solution, but mold continues to show up in random places on an almost daily basis. I've not used the vinegar on my sony A7. Not sure if I should do that. Does anyone have any advice on how to keep the mold under control or keep it from coming back, or been in a similar situation? I've heard about lens fungus, but have never dealt with it growing on the actual body of the camera. Thanks in advance for your help.
I don't have access to any sort of dry box either..